# How to edit Process Builder

Tags: process-builder

How to edit object name in the process builder? I entered the object name wrong by mistake and saved it. now i am unable to change it. how to change the object name?

Comment: You have to clone and work on clone. If that does not allow object change you have to start fresh

Answer (score 1):

Its not possible to change object name once you have created a process builder.

You need to create a new Process builder for this. You can delete the existing one.